# Why Cucumber knows where spec factories are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

I am working on a project that is using Cucumber and Rspec.  There are factories defined in /spec/factories but Cucumber is using those factories too.

However, there is no definition of that requirement in the env.rb file in /features/support/env.rb. So I fail to see this kind of thing anywhere in the cucumber folder:

```
require 'spec/factories'
```

How does Cucumber know where the factories are?

Answer (score 1):

FactoryGirl loads the factories from spec/factories ; it's [hardcoded](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/d727c8867db489356ead7ae0531a0a5ec9b73bfa/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb#L13-L17).

As for where is Cucumber loading FactoryGirl, you may find `require 'spec_helper'` in your features/support/env.rb and `require 'factory_girl'` in your `spec/spec_helper.rb`.